# How to remove adjacent duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Orange
Orange
Orange
Apple
Apple
Apple
Orange
Orange
Grapes
Grapes
```

I want to remove any same value adjacent to each other, not distinct among all. The result should be

```
Orange
Apple
Orange
Grapes
```

Here orange repeats but it was from a different section. So that is fine. 
I do not have any other supporting column to do partitioning. How to do this in sql server

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as an "adjacent" row unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff valuable info:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Let me assume that your data has a column that specifies the ordering.

In that case, you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(col) over (order by ordering_col) as prev_col
      from t
     ) t
where prev_col is null or prev_col <> col;
```

If you want to delete the rows, you can use:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             lag(col) over (order by ordering_col) as prev_col
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where prev_col = col;
```